# Spring MVC handles request after page rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spring, tomcat, webpage-rendering

I have a Spring MVC application(2.5.6) and after a page render, spring MVC does several requests as GET method which cause the erasing of my current command value. 
It was working under tomcat 5.5 and I updated the application to tomcat 6.0.35 but I have the same problem with Jetty also. I'm wondering weather Spring MVC 2.5.6 behaves differently under tomcat 5.5 and tomcat 6.x
The business scearis is as following:
use create a Vacancy
Without saving it, he click on Preview button
Than, there is a button to go back(not the browser's one), and after clicking on back button, the edit form is displayed with validation errors on all the fields and any value is kept.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that some obscure get requests are done load image on the URL supposed to be used with POST requests, and Spring MVC recreate a new command when it receive a GET request. So the problem isn't connected with Spring MVC itself, but I have to find out why two GET requests are done to load images. It may be even a CSS issue.